# Android Kotlin comparing two long dates

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two long dates : one from the room db and one from the current system time. I am trying to compare the two dates and if they are more than 24 hours apart I want to initialize some logic.

I am using kotlin and my app is targeted to api 23 so the newer date time library for API O and above is not useful at this time.

If anyone could help with the logic it would be greatly appreciated.

```
val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val lastUpdated = dateUtil.convertServerStringDateToLong(coolDown?.lastUpdated!!)
    val timeSinceLastUpdate = currentTime.minus(lastUpdated)
    return currentTime.minus(timeSinceLastUpdate) > TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)
```

Comment: *I am using kotlin and my app i stargeted to api 23 so the newer date time library for API O and above is not useful at this time.* ... Are you sure? You can use `java.time` via [API Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support), at least.

Comment: try DateUtils.isToday(long roomDBTimeInMilliseconds) if not then past date

Comment: @deHaar I added 4 lines of code to my question but its not working properly I dont think, I need it to return true if its been more than 24 hours > else false

Comment: https://www.ict.social/kotlin/oop/date-and-time-in-kotlin-parsing-and-comparing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the following line:

```
return currentTime.minus(timeSinceLastUpdate) > TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)
```

It should be

```
return timeSinceLastUpdate > TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)
```

because you want to check if the time since the last update is over `24` hours.